# SQL Server foreign key partitions for two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datatables

I'm new to databases and I don't understand how partitions work. I tried to understand some examples but I'm still lost. I just need to make a partition of table `Persona` basing me of `idUbicacion`, for each different foreign key I need the partition. I'm thank for you help. :)

```
CREATE TABLE Ubicacion
(
    numero int identity(1,1) primary key NOT NULL,
    pais varchar(200) NOT NULL
    provincia varchar(200) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE Persona
(
    id int identity(1,1) primary key NOT NULL,
    nombre varchar(500),
    cedula int,
    nacionalidad varchar(200),
    idUbicacion int foreign key references Ubicacion(id) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Partition is a different concept than foreign key. I suggest you find some documents that can teach you those concepts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are partitioning a table then you need to define a partitioning key which needs to be included in the primary key. For example (this is not the right syntax just a pseudo code):

```
CREATE TABLE Ubicacion(
    numero int identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
    pais varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    provincia varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    primary key (numero, provincia)
) PARTITION BY provincia;
```

Then you need to add this extra field to all your foreign keys if possible:

```
CREATE TABLE Persona(
    id int identity(1,1) primary key NOT NULL,
    nombre varchar(500),
    cedula int,
    nacionalidad varchar(200),
    provincia varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    idUbicacion int NOT NULL,
    foreign key (idUbicacion, provincia) references Ubicacion(id, provincia) 
);
```

Not easy right? So I have 2 recommendation for you:

1. Don't partition a primary table (dimension table) only a fact table.
2. If you use partitioning then don't use foreign keys.